# How can I use lambdaj in my application

Tags: java, lambdaj

This may sound like a stupid question, but how can I start to use lambdaj library? I downloaded the lambdaj.jar and put it in the lib directory in my webapp together with other jar files. But I can't import any of the classes. Do I need to build the jar using maven? 
Thanks in advance!

David

Comment: And consider using the lambdaj-2.0-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: Adding it to `WEB-INF/lib` is sufficient to add it to your runtime classpath, but you will also need it to be present on your build class path so that your development tools can see it. How you do this depends on what tools you are using. Eclipse? NetBeans? IntelliJ? Javac at the command line?

Comment: Yes, now I realized after adding the jars to the WEB-INF/lib directory, I also need to add the jars to the Eclipse java project libraries list. Now I can use the library. I've been taking IDE for granted, can't code without it now. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add it to the rest of your libraries for compilation and you need to package it with the rest of jars when building/packaging.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to add the jar to the CLASSPATH.